# Why is there a voltage when following a larger resistor versus a smaller one?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, basic

I'm given two otherwise identical circuits with +3V input on the top and -3V input on the bottom.

There are two resistors between these voltages and an ideal diode between those resistors alongside a diode attached to ground.

Circuit A has a 1 kohm resistor after the +3V and a 3 kohm resistor before the -3V.

Circuit B has the resistor values switched. A 3 kohm resistor follows the positive source and a 1 kohm resistor precedes the negative source.

Why does B have a voltage after the diode but A does not?

[image]

I checked these values on Multisim and it's acting as if the diodes are two shorts on A, but the ground diode is an open on B.

[image] [image]

I'm trying to understand why it behaves this way, specifically:

- Why D1 is reverse-biased in B but not in A?
- Why doesn't that also apply to D2?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your misunderstanding is here. Are you confused as to why D1 is reverse-biased in one condition and not in the other?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. You've written your first paragraph as one long sentence and it's hard to decode what it means, let alone answer it. Same for the last one. Please can you edit it and rephrase it into short, distinct sentences. Don't just put full stops in, obviously, it won't be any clearer. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made an edit to try to clarify it. 
As far as the misunderstanding @Hearth, you'd be correct. I'm not understanding what's driving the bias and why D1 and D2 are behaving the same in circuit a but different in b.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've split it a lot to make each point distinct and clear. Sometimes, many separate paragraphs helps a lot.

Comment: `Why does B have a voltage after the diode but A does not?` ... they both have a voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's fine to do so for series arranged parts, I swapped the positions of \$D_2\$ and \$R_2\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff0tNn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above change allows a slightly improved "mental shift" by setting both diodes with one end against a voltage source of some kind. That way, if the diode is **on** then the voltage at the other side of the diode is more readily known.

Now, look at the above schematic just a little more closely. If \$D_1\$ is **on** then \$V_a\$ is known to be one diode drop above ground. If this is an ideal diode with a voltage drop of \$0\:\text{V}\$ then \$V_a=0\:\text{V}\$ if \$D_1\$ is **on**. If \$D_1\$ is **off** then it doesn't impact the circuit.

Now look at \$D_2\$. Whether or not \$D_1\$ is **on**, you can see that \$D_2\$ must be **on**. So this is a given. Because of that fact, we can assign \$V_b\$ to one diode drop above \$V_2\$. (If this is an ideal diode with a voltage drop of \$0\:\text{V}\$ then \$V_b=-3\:\text{V}\$. If this is an ideal diode with a voltage drop of \$650\:\text{mV}\$, for example, then \$V_b=-2.35\:\text{V}\$.)

This allows us to simplify the schematic further:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJDeEm.png)</sup>

On the left, I've removed \$D_2\$ since we've decided it is always **on**. On the right, I've converted the two voltage sources and the two resistors (which form a divider) into their Thevenin equivalent, where: \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_1\,R_2+V_b\,R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$ and \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{R_1\,R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$.

Two possibilities for an ideal diode with a voltage drop of \$0\:\text{V}\$:

- \$R_1=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$: \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{3\:\text{V}\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega-3\:\text{V}\cdot 1\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+3\:\text{k}\Omega}=+1\:\text{V}\$. Therefore, \$D_1\$ is forward-biased and **on**.
- \$R_1=3\:\text{k}\Omega\$: \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{3\:\text{V}\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega-3\:\text{V}\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+3\:\text{k}\Omega}=0\:\text{V}\$. \$D_1\$ has \$0\:\text{V}\$ across it and it's open to interpretation (since these are non-existent ideal diodes) as to whether or not you consider \$D_1\$ **on** but there will be no current through it, regardless, as there will be none left over for it to sink.

Similar possibilities exist for an ideal diode with a voltage drop of, say, \$650\:\text{mV}\$. But now the picture is a little clearer (and the answer perhaps closer to what simulator might show.)

- \$R_1=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$: \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{3\:\text{V}\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega+\left(650\:\text{mV}-3\:\text{V}\right)\cdot 1\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+3\:\text{k}\Omega}=+1.6625\:\text{V}\$. Therefore, \$D_1\$ is forward-biased and **on**.
- \$R_1=3\:\text{k}\Omega\$: \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{3\:\text{V}\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega+\left(650\:\text{mV}-3\:\text{V}\right)\cdot 3\:\text{k}\Omega}{1\:\text{k}\Omega+3\:\text{k}\Omega}=+0.4875\:\text{V}\$. That's not sufficient so \$D_1\$ is **off**.

Of course, the reality is that a diode is a non-linear device and if forward-biased at all will be **on** to some degree and conducting current. Even if that's only \$400\:\text{mV}\$ or even less, say \$150\:\text{mV}\$. But then you need to deal with the next level up in modeling a diode -- the Shockley diode equation. For another day.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does B have a voltage after the diode but A does not?

A is grounded so by definition that is 0V on the -ve side or Cathode.
So A has a pullup voltage BEFORE and B has a voltage AFTER. yet in A both cathodes are near 0V due to choice of resistors to try to match currents.  (close enuf)

[image]

Here you see probe voltages and currents for A) and B) and I added with no diodes in the middle to match the R values in B)

Notice the greater rt. diode current >0.7V makes the cathode below ground  and now the left side diode voltage drops since the Anodes (+) are tied together aka "common anode".

In the middle you see the the 3K +1K goes to -1.5V   .

Then with diodes added in B) both Anodes are -1V and the right side Cathode is -1.7 !

So the result was drastic the Left diode turns off and has -1V reverse bias.

Comment: Agree with your answer but if someone is asking for help with understanding Ohm's law they probably don't already understand how a current mirror works or know how to use an NPN or PNP transistor. Simplifying this would probably improve it's helpfulness.

Comment: Can confirm with @user1850479. I know it's a basic thing I should know but teachers I've come into contact with always assume we know these things because it's so rudimentary to them that "why wouldn't you?" So unfortunately I don't know anything about current mirrors.

Comment: sorry . the problem with this site is users don't publish their background to identify their education or experience level. and I like to address the question for a wider audience including more advanced ( my bad).

Comment: revised to show the logic without equations and simulation https://tinyurl.com/y7n2a255

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of theory.

This is an example of circuits containing only resistors and ideal diodes, i.e. diodes that can be only on or off. This kind of exercises are classic in circuit theory.

It can be shown that in such a circuit there is just one solution and that solution can be found by "guessing" the state of each diode (either on or off). If you guess right diodes supposed to be ON will have a positive forward ***current*** (current will flow from anode to cathode), if they are OFF they will have a negative forward ***voltage*** (cathode at lower potential than anode).

So, in theory, one could reach a solution by exhaustion, i.e. by solving
\$2^n\$ circuits, with \$n\$ the number of diodes, in each of which you assign a different set of states for the diodes: ON diodes will be substituted by short circuits, OFF diodes by open circuits, you solve a purely resistive circuit and verify afterward whether or not the tried states are compatible with the voltages and current found by solving that circuit.

This process can be sped up considerably with experience and a bit of educated guessing. If you guess right you can reach the solution quite rapidly (remember that if you find a solution, *that* is *the* solution, since it is unique).

Let's examine your circuits and for convenience let's call the upper resistor R1 and the lower R2.

In circuit A it is easy to see that both diodes must be ON (try to solve the circuit in the 3 other cases and you'll find incompatible results). In this case both diodes are short circuits, hence the lower leg of R1 is at 0V and so is the upper leg of R2 (and V = 0). Then by Ohm's law in R1 flows a current I1 = 3V/1k=3mA, in R2 flows a current I2 = 3V/3k=1mA and by KCL
I = I1 - I2 = 2mA > 0. Since I is the forward current of D1 and I>0, then we confirm that D1 is ON. Moreover since I2 is the forward current of D2 and it's positive, also D2 is confirmed to be ON. We confirmed the state of both diodes, *so this is the solution for circuit A*.

In circuit B, however, D1 must be OFF (and D2 ON). The diodes can't be both ON as before because if you redo the steps I've shown you for circuit A, you'll end up with
I1 = 1mA, I2 = 3mA and I = -2mA. This would mean a negative forward current for D1, which is incompatible with its ON state.

So let's try with D1 OFF and D2 ON. In this case the two resistors are in series and I1 = I2 = 6V/(1k+3k)=1.5mA. Since I2 > 0, we confirm that D2 is ON. Moreover V = -3V + R2 * 1.5mA = -3V + 1.5V = -1.5V. And since V is the voltage at D1 anode (being D2 a short) and since its cathode is at 0V, D1 is reverse biased (negative forward voltage), confirming it is indeed OFF.
So we confirmed both diodes state, hence *this is the solution for circuit B*.

I leave you for exercise to check that other combinations of states for the diodes won't lead you to confirm one or more of those states.